# function to render similor or best match color swatch in shopify

Tags: shopify, themes, liquid, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

i,m facing an issue using Pipeline theme and in many of my products having custom color variants like "Green/White" or "New Light Coral" but can see in theme code in swatches.json there,s only colors for
{
"coral": "#ff7f50"
},
{
"green": "#008000"
},
{
"ivory": "#f5ecda"
so i want to show best match or similor color to my products like for "Green/White" color it should show "green": "#008000" and for "New Light Coral" it should show "coral": "#ff7f50" on color swatch below is the theme liquid which is responsible to render the color template-swatch.liquid

```
{%- if settings.swatches_enable and settings.swatches_collection_enable -%}
  <script data-swatch-template type="text/x-template">
    <radio-swatch class="swatch__button{% if settings.swatches_squares %} swatch__button--square{% endif %}">
      {% raw %}
        <input type="radio"
          name="grouped-{{ it.product_id }}"
          value="{{ it.color }}"
          id="{{ it.uniq }}"
          tabindex="-1">
        <label for="{{ it.uniq }}"
          data-swatch="{{ it.color }}"
          data-swatch-variant="{{ it.variant }}"
          data-swatch-image="{{ it.image }}"
          data-swatch-image-id="{{ it.image_id }}"
          data-swatch-index="{{ it.index }}"
          tabindex="0">
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ it.color }}</span>
        </label>
      {% endraw %}
    </radio-swatch>
  </script>
{%- endif -%}
```

i,m tryiing to make a function but its not applying below is my script to do my task

```
{%- if settings.swatches_enable and settings.swatches_collection_enable and settings.show_swatches_in_sidebar -%}
  <script data-swatch-template type="text/x-template">
    <radio-swatch class="swatch__button{% if settings.swatches_squares %} swatch__button--square{% endif %}">
      {% raw %}
        <input type="radio"
          name="grouped-{{ it.product_id }}"
          value="{{ it.color }}"
          id="{{ it.uniq }}"
          tabindex="-1">
        <label for="{{ it.uniq }}"
          data-swatch="{{ it.color }}"
          data-swatch-variant="{{ it.variant }}"
          data-swatch-image="{{ it.image }}"
          data-swatch-image-id="{{ it.image_id }}"
          data-swatch-index="{{ it.index }}"
          tabindex="0">
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ it.color }}</span>
        </label>
        {%- if it.color_contains_slash -%}
          {% assign custom_color_parts = it.color | split: '/' %}
          {%- assign found_custom_color = false -%}

          {%- for part in custom_color_parts -%}
            {%- assign swatch_entry = swatches | map: part | compact | first -%}
            {%- if swatch_entry -%}
              <div class="custom-color-swatch" style="background-color: {{ swatch_entry }}"></div>
              {%- assign found_custom_color = true -%}
              {%- break -%}
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- endfor -%}

          {%- unless found_custom_color -%}
            {%- assign closest_color = find_closest_color(custom_color_parts) -%}
            {%- if closest_color -%}
              <div class="custom-color-swatch" style="background-color: {{ closest_color }}"></div>
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- endunless -%}
        {%- endif -%}
      {% endraw %}
    </radio-swatch>
  </script>
{%- endif -%}
```